# How to access data attributes in React Native?

Tags: react-native

In React the best practice is to put an onClick event on the parent node and access the children's attributes with event.target like below. How do you do this in React Native?

```
handleClick = (event) => {
    this.setState({
            color: event.target.dataset.color
    })
}

render(){
    return(
        <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <div data-color="red"></div>
            <div data-color="green"></div>
            <div data-color="yellow"></div>
            <div data-color="blue"></div>
            <div data-color="gray"></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

In React Native the only way I found how to do this was by adding an onPress for each child... The question is:  is this best practice? Are there better ways, like adding data attributes and access them somehow?

```
handlePress = (color) => {
    this.setState({
        color
    })
}

render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this, "red")}>
                <View></View>
            <TouchableOpacity/>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this, "green")}>
                <View></View>
            <TouchableOpacity/>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this, "yellow")}>
                <View></View>
            <TouchableOpacity/>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this, "blue")}>
                <View></View>
            <TouchableOpacity/>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this, "gray")}>
                <View></View>
            <TouchableOpacity/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: The only thing that I see here is that you bind the `onPress` callbacks directly in the render method. This will lead to new methods every render. Other than that, I think the main thing is that `react-native` or event the underlying java thingy doesn't have event bubbling (I haven't seen it, but I'm also the opposite of an expert). I do see some patterns, eg. all your touchables look the same. So you could create a component that takes an array of metadata, creates the buttons, and when pressed, passes that metadata back (essentially creating some form component [maybe already exists?]).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component for your inner views. something like this:

```
const InnerComp = (props) => {
  const customColor = props.color;
  return <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={()=>props.onPress(customColor)}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: customColor}}/>
  <TouchableOpacity/>;
};
```

And then your main component will look something like this:

```
handlePress = (color) => {
    this.setState({
        color
    })
}

render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <InnerComp onPress={handlePress} color="red"/>
            <InnerComp onPress={handlePress} color="green"/>
            <InnerComp onPress={handlePress} color="yellow"/>
            <InnerComp onPress={handlePress} color="blue"/>
            <InnerComp onPress={handlePress} color="gray"/>
        </View>
    )
}
```